# How to do Foreign Key reverse lookup with related name DJANGO2.1

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, foreign-keys

How can i possibly get the result mentioned below of a ForeignKey reverse lookup? I have seen other similar questions but I believe I will be able to understand this concept with my current problem.

Below are my tables.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_invoices')
    number = models.IntegerField(default=invoice_number, null=True)
    select = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')
    product = models.ForeignKey('Service', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoice_items')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

class Service(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='services')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

What i am trying to achieve is When i access the detail page of Invoice from the list of invoice: I want to be able to access information from Service table and display `name, description, price` fields from Service table.

```
def invoice_detail(request, id):
    invoice = get_object_or_404(Invoice, id=id)

    context = {'invoice':invoice}
    return render(request, 'product/dashboard/invoice_detail.html', context)
```

Not sure whether this is the right way to do it or should I just create a ManytoMany Relationship.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can do like this in template:

```
{% for invoiceitem in invoice.items.all %}
    {{ invoiceitem.product.name }}
    {{ invoiceitem.product.description }}
    {{ invoiceitem.product.price }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or in python:

```
for invoiceitem in invoice.items.all():
    print(invoiceitem.product.name)
    print(invoiceitem.product.description)
    print(invoiceitem.product.price)
```

Comment: thank you for your response. what would the views.py look like in this case?

Comment: to be honest, in your case, you don't need to modify the view. you can use the template code.